# retrieve multiple cookies from winhttp header

Tags: c++, winhttp

I want to retrieve the cookies from winhttpheader.The problem is that header is in this form:

```
Header-Contents
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: name=xyz; Path=/
; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: token=45e8e18440859e769a56b0e1191bea8f1cc049d1; Path=/
; secure; httponly
```

Now using winhttp_query_set_cookie , I am only getting name field,not token.

```
  do
   {
           bQuerySizeResult=WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE,WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,NULL,&nCookie,WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
        WCHAR *strCookie=new WCHAR[nCookie];
         LPCTSTR ws1;
              bQuerySizeResult=WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE,WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,strCookie,&nCookie,WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);

        std::wcout<<"\n" <<strCookie[0]<<" "<<strCookie[1];
        ws1=strCookie;
        std::wstring  ws(ws1);
        std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
        LPSTR mystring ;
        mystring= const_cast<LPSTR>(str.c_str());
      std::cout<<"\nthe str is "<<mystring<<"\n";
}while(bQuerySizeResult);*/
```

Comment: do{
bQuerySizeResult=WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE,WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,NULL,&nCookie,WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
WCHAR *strCookie=new WCHAR[nCookie];
LPCTSTR ws1;
bQuerySizeResult=WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest,WINHTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE,WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,strCookie,&nCookie,WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
std::wcout<<"\n" <<strCookie[0]<<" "<<strCookie[1];
ws1=strCookie;
std::wstring  ws(ws1);
std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
LPSTR mystring ;
 mystring= const_cast<LPSTR>(str.c_str());
std::cout<<"\nthe str is "<<mystring<<"\n";
}while(bQuerySizeResult);

Comment: instead of comment edit your code and paste it.